# Install new Java on old system

Tags: 12.04, java

I have old `Ubuntu Linux 2.6.8 i686` with `JRE 1.4` in it. I have no possiblity to upgrade system, but I would like to upgrade my Java.

I suppose I can have big problems while installing newest java to my old system. What is the highest java version I can choose?

Anyway I was trying to install newest java by downloading and extracting jre-8u60-linux-i586.gz. When I run java from bin directory I have message:

```
Error: dl failure on line 893
Error: failed /opt/jre1.8.0_60/lib/i386/client/libjvm.so, because /lib/tls/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.4' not found (required by /opt/jre1.8.0_60/lib/i386/client/libjvm.so)
```

What is that and how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you like to install java, it might be the best and easiest method to use webupd8s java ppa.

There you can install oracel java 6/7/8/9 whithout hassle, even in 12.04.

here is the ppa: https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java?field.series_filter=precise

here is webupd8s blogentry on how to install java 8 (should be the sanest choice atm): http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html

Have Fun!

P.S.: delete /opt/jre1.8.0_60/ and always try to stick with ppas, do not download and extract "programms" as long as you do not know exactly what you are doing.